# F-Statistic and F-distribution

Tags: self-study, f-statistic

I am reading [ISLP](https://www.statlearning.com/) chapter 3.2 about multiple linear regressions.
F-statistic seems like to be a statistic calculated per sample. But also we know that it is just and estimation for the stat on whole population.

In that case, I wanted to verify this thing about F-distribution.

- Is F-distribution a sampling distribution of something over all possible sampling in given population ?
- Or is F-distribution a sampling distribution of something over all possible populations with?

I am not looking for a proof. Just some clarification.